# spring rabbit message route issue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have the following route for my message:
[image]

1. Client sends http (or rest) request
2. He expect to get reply in request scope (request-response)
3. System computes new correlationId
4. His request comes to the rabbit queue1, then to the rabbit queue2, etc
5. Th queue2 sends reply to the special output queue with correct correlationId
6. Client listens this queue and if his corrId comes, takes result and send back to he client (via concurrenthashmap ia a spring singleton bean)

I have the following issues:

1. If I run 2-3 nodes instead of 1, 10k messages procession time remains the same, strange
2. I have to wait for output queue using Thread.sleep() - is there any better solution?
3. I have to deal with 100k/second system, is it a good architecture?
4. I have a global ThreadTaskExecutor  in my code, so listening for proper corrId performing in a separate thread. I feel it`s not good to have a global unlimited thread pool in the app, am I right?

Please help me with this system, maybe you have better ideas how to organize it, because I have 20 messages/second rate now, in queue1 I only select one record from db and insert another record, is this speed is ok? Please help

Comment: Why doesn't `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()` help you ?

Comment: Thank you,but I don't understand how to use it if I send a message from one queue but receive from another. And btw, I will deal with over 10k messaves per second, is this way will work? Please hell me, I always get null with sendandreceive. Thank you

Comment: The `RabbitTemplate` has `queue` option for these `sendAndReceive` cases. But other side (server) really should take care about correct reply correlation: use `replyToAddress` to send a response to you. Otherwise you should have a separate `ListenerContainer` for that queue and correlate replies with requests manually.

Comment: Thank you `and correlate replies with requests manually` - this is exactly what i have done so far. Every time my rest service accepts request, it creates new thread, send message to rabbit, and lock this thread until special lambda by java8 is called from message listener container of output queue listener. And this way works, but the issue is for 10k requests per second I have to create 10k threads in memory, and it's bad. SendAndReceive would be a great option but I really feel it's not acceptable in my case. My reply-to address may vary at runtime, I can't stick to rabbit template

Comment: PS. Depending on condition reply-to address may be different. So we get the situation when message is being sent from point A to point B, but between these point I will have 10-20 resending between other queues. And I can't just write Object o =rt.sendAndReceive(with corrId). How rabbit will understand that it's still my message after 10 resending times? So I decided to listen output query as-is, waiting and checking for responses in order of their arrival. Please help me if you see better solution. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for delay. OK. Let's come back to your original Threading solution. How about not create thread-per-request but use `FixedThreadPoolExecutor` ?

Comment: Thank you, if I use fixed thread pool, I always get procession speed ~20 messages/second, but if I use cached thread pool, I get 150 ms/second. The issue is SynchronousQueue does the trick, but BlockingQueue limits bandwidth dramatically, not depending on pool size. I need maximum possible performance, fixed thread pool, in it's any form, gives me fixed bandwidth of my thread pool, and it's low. Please tell me your concerns about it.

Comment: Well, Take a look, please, to Reactor: http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#work

Comment: Wow, thank you, but I`m not sure it works with rabbit mq on multiple servers, I need 10 different machines, or want you to say that I may use it only on output queue - to grab results?